What does "origine: pur ordinaire" mean in the list of stocks in a French brokerage account?
What does "origine: pur ordinaire" mean in the list of stocks in a brokerage account?

I understand that an "action ordinaire" means:

An ordinary share is a type of share that gives voting rights and pays dividends, a
a type of share that gives voting rights and pays dividends, and which is the most common form of share.

But I don't get the meaning of "pur" (which translates into "pure" in English).
